# SQl Query to Find Max Value from Min Results Set

Tags: t-sql, subquery, max, min

Is it possible to write a query that finds the maximum value from a group of minimum values that are retrieved in the same query?

It's easy enough to order the minimums by decreasing value (which leaves the desired max value at the top of the list) but I am curious if a query could be constructed that would return only that value and nothing else.

Query that retrieves minimums:

```
SELECT dbo.tblDevices.Status
, L.Device_id
, MIN(L.DateAndTime) As 'End Date'
FROM dbo.tblDeviceLocation AS L
JOIN dbo.tblDevices
ON L.Device_id = dbo.tblDevices.Device_id
GROUP BY L.Device_id, dbo.tblDevices.Status
```

I want to find the row with the max of these mins.  I thought of trying to use a subquery, but I don't see it working because it's returning N-minimum value number of rows.  Then I thought of using COMPUTE, because this could be considered a sub-total, but this also does not work because you can't sub-total something that's not being grouped (L.DateAndTime).

Any thoughts?

*Edit:
I just came across this article http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-maximum-value-without-using-aggregate/ which from a cursory quick read might be applicable.  I'll update when/if I discover something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an ORDER BY and if you're using SQL-Server TOP 1 if you're using MySQL then you have to use LIMIT 1 at the end of the query

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.tblDevices.Status
, L.Device_id
, MIN(L.DateAndTime) As 'End Date'
FROM dbo.tblDeviceLocation AS L
JOIN dbo.tblDevices
ON L.Device_id = dbo.tblDevices.Device_id
GROUP BY L.Device_id, dbo.tblDevices.Status
ORDER BY MIN(L.DateAndTime) DESC // order by max value
```

Comment: @Snake_Plissken no problem, we've all had those days. If this solved your issue don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.